# Syncthing reports version unknown-dev on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: package-management, 19.10

After upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10, Syncthing reports version "unknown-dev" instead of 1.1.4 (as reported by apt).

Because of this, other devices assume that it's a really old version of Syncthing.

Comment: This is a bug with the current version, and has been reported to the package maintainers: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/syncthing/+bug/1847018